# Java reading a string from a text(txt) file

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader, filereader

> Rod
>   Rae
>   Bryan
>   Shiroe
>   Ric
>   Kirito
>   Asuna
>   Elsa
>   Akutabe
>   Shino

I have that list saved in a text file. If I were to enter Rod, it should say "Exists" and if I enter a name that is not on the list, it should say "Does not exist." But what is happening on my code is that it reads the file **per line** and prints "Does not exist" if it does not match the string line.
So if I were to enter a name that does not exist in the txt file, it would print 10 "Does not exist" lines.

This is my code below:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    out.print("Enter name: ");
    String name = in.nextLine();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("name.txt"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains(name)) {
            out.println("Exists");
            break;
        } else {
            out.println("Does not exist");
        }
    }
    br.close();
```

An example of a what would be output is:

name = Kirito

> Does not exist
>   Does not exist
>   Does not exist
>   Does not exist
>   Exists

Why does my program print so many `Does not exist` before finding the exact match?

Comment: And from Log Horizon xD Glad you noticed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `break`ing the loop if the name exists, so you should only print the "not exists" message if the loop **doesn't** break:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
out.print("Enter name: ");
String name = in.nextLine();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("name.txt"));
String line;
boolean nameFound = false;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains(name)) {
        out.println("Exists");
        nameFound = true;
        break;
}
if (!nameFound) {
    out.println("Does not exist");
}
br.close();
```

Comment: Ooooh I see now. It acts like a on/off switch. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Use a `boolean` to remember whether you have found a match, and display "Does not exist" only after checking every item and only if you have not found a match.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. You are just preemptively printing the error message. I would have also used equals instead of contains and pre-loaded the entire file into. HashSet if multiple queries need to be answered

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
out.print("Enter name: ");
String name = in.nextLine();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("name.txt"));
String line;
boolean found = false;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains(name)) {
        out.println("Exists");
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
             out.println("Does not exist");
}
br.close();
```

Comment: I'm still not familiar with Java so I don't know most of the terms like HashSet :( Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    PrintStream out = System.out;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    out.print("Enter name: ");
    String name = in.readLine();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("name.txt"));
    String line;
    boolean ifexist = false;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains(name)) {
            ifexist = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ifexist) {
        out.print("Exist");
    } else {
        out.println("Does not exist");
    }
    br.close();
```

Add a boolean var default false, when exist set it to true and break. Than output.